# How to create dropdown in an editable table which has multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp4V6.png)

I am creating a multi-line insert table using PHP, jquery, and AJAX. With this, the user can add more rows or remove rows from the table.

Can anyone help me how to create a drop down in the column? I have 4 columns in the table and I want a drop-down on the item name. I am attaching the snap of the table. 
Please help me guys, I am a beginner.

```
    [<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</head>
<body>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <br/>
        <h2 align="center">Multiple Line Insert into MySql using Ajax and jQuery in PHP</h2>
        <br/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%">Item Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
                    <th width="45%">Description</th>
                    <th width="10%">price</th>
                    <th width="5%"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_desc"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_price"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count =1;
        $('#add').click(function(){
            count = count + 1;
            var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
            html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
            html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
            html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_desc'></td>";
            html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_price'></td>";
            html_code += "<td><button type= 'button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+" 'class= btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";
            html_code +="</tr>";
            $('#crud_table').append(html_code);

        });
        $(document).on('click','.remove', function(){
            var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
            $('#' + delete_row).remove();

        });
    });
</script>][1]
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812153/689579

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not what i want to know... have u seen the image i have attached? i have a table and i want drop down i the first coulmn.

Comment: Yes I looked at your image. Do you want `<td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>` to be a dropdown? Or do you just want to put a dropdown inside -> `<td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"><select>....</select></td>`? If the 1st, then use the link I suggested (you have to change the `<p>` to `<td>`. If the 2nd, not sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are expecting a list item in the menu row itself.
You can refer this for [bootstrap drop-down](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) classes.

So this is the image ,  [image: Click here]

And I'm attaching the code snippet as well. As few of them have suggested, add jquery functions to add/remove drop-down items.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        <br/>
        <h2 align="center">Multiple Line Insert into MySql using Ajax and jQuery in PHP</h2>
        <br/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%">
                    <!-- place this div where ever you want it to be-->
                        <div class="dropdown show">
                            <button class="btn bg-white dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Item Name
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            </th>
                    <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
                    <th width="45%">Description</th>
                    <th width="10%">price</th>
                    <th width="5%"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_desc"></td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" class="item_price"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Place the drop-down where ever you want it to be.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/xzOrWy

```
$('#add').on('click', function(e){
  $("#DataRow").clone().appendTo("#crud_table");

})
```